# How to programmatically set the constraints of the subViews of a UIPageViewController?

Tags: swift

I have contained the subViews of a UIPageViewController within a UIView so that my screen has a partial scrollView container. However, the subViewControllers extend beyond both, the UIView that is supposed to contain the (horizontal/swiping page style) scrollView and the screen of the device.

I have already tried to use autolayout constraints but the subViews still go beyond the device screen.

Here is the UIView that contains the subViews of the UIPVC:

```
let pagingContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

and here is the set up within viewDidLoad():

```
let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    addChild(pageController)
    pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
    pagingContainer.addSubview(pageController.view)
```

In case I haven't articulated properly:
What I wish for to happen is that the bottom half of my screen is a horizontal-page-style swiping scrollView that contains x number of subViewControllers (under UIPVC), and the size of subViewControllers are limited to the size of the UIView(pagingContainer).

Comment: am I asking a wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might understand what you're asking.
It should be pretty simple, set your left/right/top/bottom constraints for the pageController.view to be equal to the pagingContainer
In my example, I'm using SnapKit, so I set the edges equal to superview (which is the paingContainer).

```
    let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    self.addChild(pageController)
    pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
    pagingContainer.addSubview(pageController.view)
    // I set up constraints with SnapKit (since I mostly use that pod)
    pageController.view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    })
    // But if I remember correctly, you can also set it like so:
    pageController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pagingContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    pageController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pagingContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    pageController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.pagingContainer.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Here is a quick gif of what it looks like.  Main view controller only has red background and a pagingContainer on the bottom half and inset of 30 on each side (to demonstrate the size of pageController being within the pagingContainer and not overflowing)
[image]

Comment: This worked for me
(I know you're not supposed to thank people here, but I did not get help from anyone else, and this worked like a charm, thank you so very much)